# NSSThread identifier

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch

is there anything like an identifier of a NSSThread? The following code:

```
NSLog(@"thread: %@",(NSThread*)aThread);
```

results in something like this:

> Thread: {name =
>   (null), num = 6}

Is there a way to get this thread number, maybe?

Best,
heinrich

Answer (score 4):

Just use the address of the NSThread instance.  There is only ever one instance representing a thread and that instance will live exactly as long as the thread.   If a thread dies and a new thread is created, you may get a new instance at the same address, but the thread number may also be re-used, too.

Answer (score 3):

You can set the name of the thread using setName: on a NSThread.

Answer (score 0):

I guess I will use a combination of object address and name. Maybe that works.
Best,
heinrich